# jQuery css place a div just below an element

Tags: jquery, css

I have [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/fCAAY/3/):

```
#bottom-div {
    z-index:999
}

<input type="text" id="main" />
<div id="bottom-div">Div to be place below the input box</div>
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />
ContentContent Conetent<br />

$("#bottom-div").hide()
    $("#main").click(function() {
   $("#bottom-div").toggle();
});
```

I want the `bottom-div` below the input box, and should be above the content, i.e. no content should block it. How can I do this with CSS and jQuery?

**EDIT**: I want it to be like an autocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Like u got div's in auto-completes like that

OK, I see what you want now.

Just add `position:absolute;` and make sure to give it a background so the content beneath it doesn't show through.

```
#bottom-div {
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fCAAY/11/

Comment: oH yes that is what i wanted :D
But now how do i put the width of the div at  most of the input box's width

Comment: You've now added two additional requests to your question in the comments. If you [edit] your question to be complete, with everything you need clearly stated, I will take another look at it.

Comment: Because when i put this : $("#bottom-div").width($("#main").width());
Its still larger than input field

Comment: Never Mind i figured out why it was so

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

`$("#bottom-div").hide();`

in your script and add a

`<br />`

after the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/fCAAY/6/

Comment: No No not like this.
Like u got div's in auto-completes like that

Answer (score 0):

either you can put the input into the div like

```
<div><input type="text" /></div>
<div>you content</div>
```

or add after the input tag `<br />`

Comment: No No not like this. Like u got div's in auto-completes like that

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a very old question and might not help the questioner but others who are also searching for the same question.

you need to  get the position and height of the input by
 var pos = $(this).position();
 var height1 = $(this).outerHeight();

and then edit the css of the div to the desired position like this and show 
$("#menu").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: (pos.top + height1)  + "px",
        left: (pos.left ) + "px",
    }).show();

```
js fiddle link:`http://jsfiddle.net/m78u8805/`
```